# Automatically change a typo error of an email address

Tags: php

I try to make a litte php script that will automaticcaly correct a typo when inserting an e-mail address in a form.

```
if (strpos($_POST["email"], "@hotmail.comm") !== false) {
    $_POST["email"] = str_replace('@hotmail.comm', '@hotmail.com', $_POST["email"]);
    goto end;
}
if (strpos($_POST["email"], "@homail.com") !== false) {
    $_POST["email"] = str_replace('@homail.com', '@hotmail.com', $_POST["email"]);
    goto end;
}
end:
```

When I test this, everything works OK for @homail.com but when I test with @hotmail.comm, the e-mail address has change to @hotmail.commm

Any idea whis this goes wrong with @hotmail.comm ?

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: works for me.  BTW you dont need the horrible goto's

Comment: @Arie, I have checked your code & enter abc@hotmail.comm. It's working fine as expected at my end.

Comment: @Arie, Please check my answer for your solution, Let me know if you still have any issues !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine to me, but `goto`, really? Assign to `$_POST`? No!

You can write this shorter and better:

```
$improvements = array('@hotmail.comm' => '@hotmail.com',
                      '@homail.com'   => '@hotmail.com');

$emailAddress = str_replace(array_keys($improvements),
                            array_values($improvements),
                            $_POST["email"]);
```

Obviously the list can be expanded without adding much code. Always try to write easy to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

@Arie, Please check below code for your solution.

```
$email = $_POST["email"];

if (strpos($email, "@hotmail.comm") !== false) { 
    $_POST["email"] = str_replace('@hotmail.comm', '@hotmail.com', $email);
}
if (strpos($email, "@homail.com") !== false) {
    $_POST["email"] = str_replace('@homail.com', '@hotmail.com', $email);
}

echo $_POST["email"];die;
```